# jboss binding address

Tags: internet-explorer, jboss, ping

I am using Mac and to test my java application on latest IE version, I need to remote login to one of our Windows server.

So I am starting jboss locally binding the address to my machine name like..

```
run.sh -b mymachine-00621323
```

After I login to remote server and ping for the machine name, i am getting proper reply.

```
ping mymachine-00621323.corp.company.com

Pinging mymachine-00621323.corp.company.com [10.138.1.116] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.138.2.116: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=61
Reply from 10.138.2.116: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=61
Reply from 10.138.2.116: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=61
Reply from 10.138.2.116: bytes=32 time=104ms TTL=61

Ping statistics for 10.238.6.116:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 104ms, Average = 35ms
```

However, If I hit the below url from IE from the same remote desktop server, it does not display the page.

```
http://mymachine-00621323.corp.company.com:8080/abc/login.xhtml
```

In IE under Tools--Internet Options--SecurityTab, I tried adding it to list of trusted sites and also ensured that the security level is at medium. It dint help either.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried binding to all addresses? Run it with `run.sh -b 0.0.0.0` and see if it works then. It may be that `mymachine-00621323
` has a different IP for you locally.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes/solutions:

- Try to bind to all addresses ( `run.sh -b 0.0.0.0` ) and see if you can connect then. Your computer hostname could be mapped to a different address locally, so you might just end up binding JBoss on localhost. (For example if you have your hostname pointed to 127.0.0.1 in your hosts file)
- Try a different browser on the remote computer and/or check for any Proxy Settings in the browser you are using. IE especially could use group-policy defined proxies which might not know how to access internal addresses.
- If none of the above work, it could be a firewall issue on the local Mac or remote Windows computer. Ping does not mean all access will work, since usually individual ports/services are enabled/blocked. If you can't connect to the JBoss port on the lowest level (by using `telnet` for example), then it might be a firewall issue.